# Reference to a subfigure

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I'm using `subfigure` for some images. To reference to them in the text, I use the `\autoref{fig:test}` command. But this doesn't matter the problem is the same with `\ref` command.

To shorten the name I used: `\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}` and to have arabic numbers instead of chars: `\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}`

Problem (still without the modifications above):
It refers to it with

> 11

, but I want to have it referred like

> 1.1

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Hello. This is some text. I'm referring to a the test image (\autoref{fig:Test1}). Or to the second image with the ref command (Abb. \ref{fig:Test2}). What I want to have: (Abb. 1.2)

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bmp0_test_image.png}
                \caption{TestCaption1}
                \label{fig:Test1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bmp0_test_image.png}
                \caption{TestCaption2}
                \label{fig:Test2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Test-Figure}\label{fig:TestFigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that show us what you have.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want the subcaptions to read e.g. *(1.1) TestCaption1*, add

  ```
  \DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}
  ```

  to the preamble, and remove the modification of `\thesubfigure`, i.e. change the `\addto` thing to

  ```
  \addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}
  ```
- If you want to keep the captions as *(1) TestCaption1*, add the following to the preamble:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure.}
  \makeatother
  ```

  References to a subfigure consists, as far as I understand, of `\p@subfigure\thesubfigure`. By redefining the former to contain a period, that is included in the reference.

Complete example, with the first option commented:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%% OPTION 1
%\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}
%\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}

%% OPTION 2
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Hello. This is some text. I'm referring to a the test image (\autoref{fig:Test1}). Or to the second image with the ref command (Abb. \ref{fig:Test2}). What I want to have: (Abb.~1.2)

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                \caption{TestCaption1}
                \label{fig:Test1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                \caption{TestCaption2}
                \label{fig:Test2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Test-Figure}\label{fig:TestFigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't need to change your `\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` to something like `\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{.\arabic{subfigure}}`, with the explicit dot. Worked for me.

In another subject, I would put the `\label{}` *inside* the `\caption{}` so LaTeX knows that this label is for:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bmp0_test_image.png}
                \caption{\label{fig:Test1}TestCaption1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bmp0_test_image.png}
                \caption{\label{fig:Test2}TestCaption2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{\label{fig:TestFigure}Test-Figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It's not necessary -- though also not harmful -- to place the `\label` *inside* the argument of `\caption`. Having the `\label` come immediately after `\caption` is just fine.

Comment: @Elton
Thank you for your input. But that's no solution for me, because after that the caption of the subfigure, for example: "(1) TestCaption1" changes to "(.1) TestCaption1"